# Oracle Socket read time out from Java, while sqlplus works

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, ubuntu-14.04, tnsnames

I've encountered a problem and searched for hours, unfortunately I have no idea what to do. I had a test system with almost zero load on windows server (Oracle + Tomcat), everything was configured correctly and connection to oracle was OK. I got a backup from oracle and restored on a ubuntu server 14.04 and brought tomcat to new server. again they'll access locally like before.

The issue is that now, i can use sqlplus and query my db and see results, but while i try the same with tomcat, I get Socket read timeout error after 2 or 3 minutes. Does anybody has ANY IDEA what to do?

p.s: i telnet local 1521 successfully, but i cannot exit telnet with no keys.
p.s: should i include any config file to question?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on the "p.s"

Comment: I solved the issue by rebooting ubuntu server. Seems something needed to reboot to apply, shall I delete the question?

Comment: I'd leave it because your solution might help someone else.

Comment: I answered my own question

Answer (score 0):

I've found my own problem, seems like some module or configuration is not applied correctly and completely. First try to "stop immediate/startup" oracle by sqlplus or start/stop "lsnr" (listener of oracle), if didn't work. Reboot whole system by "sudo shutdown -r now" [be carefull with it] and It has a good chance to work, as it did for me.

I wish it helps somebody :)